# Create sql tables dynamically

Tags: php, sql, database, create-table

I have a table named project which contain 4 columns(ID,NAME,FEATURE,DOWNLOAD).For each entry in the 'project' I need to create a new table in the same database with the name pro1,  pro2, pro3 and so on. In my web UI, I have to give a button for creating a new table for each new project, then what should be the sql query for that? I use php. The user should be able to add new projects in the 'project' table and then on a button click or automatically a new table is to be created dynamically with the naming convention I have shown above . I cannot add all the features to the 'project' table due to some other reasons, that is why a new table is created for each project..Thanks in advance

Comment: That's a really bad idea. A much better alternative would be to add another key column "projectId" to each table you would duplicate that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On button click you could do the following:

- Get the number of rows currently present in `project`, say `$nor`
- Increment `$nor` by 1
- Run the `CREATE TABLE` query using `"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
  pro".$nor`

Comment: how to get number of rows currently present? your idea seems to work

Comment: `$nor = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM project"));`  I'm assuming you're using `mysql_*` functions. Be advised that they are going to be deprecated soon. You better switch to PDO or MySQLi if that is the case